python `(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds` does not return 0 seconds
I'm working with python 3.12.4 and using the standard library datetime.
I am expecting the difference between two datetime.now to be zero. Instead I get a number like 86399.
import datetime

print((datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds)  # returns 86399

Anyone knows why this is happening technically?
If I run something like this
a = dt.datetime.now()
b = dt.datetime.now()
print((b - a).seconds)  # returns 0

then the result is zero as expected.

Try print((a - b).seconds)

Have you tried printing the complete timedelta, not just its .seconds?

It is because you are subtracting a time in the past with current time.
The equivalent in terms of your second code is
(a-b).seconds

Which returns invalid timedelta object.
